# Downloading Tensorflow 2.0 GPU version On Mac OS

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm on a Mac and trying to download tensorflow 2.0 for GPU but every way I try to do it I get an error of this form:

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"
```

I've tried these ways to download it with Python 3.6:

`pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0`

`pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`

I'm able to install other versions of tensorflow-gpu but not the 2.0 version. Is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gpu is supported for macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later currently.

See [tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)
The commands works on linux but doesn't work on mac.